# Let $g:[0,1] \times [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be a $C^1$ function, then the partial derivative commutes with integration over $[0,1]$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

We wish to demonstrate that:
$$\frac{d}{dz}\int^{1}_{0} f(x,z) ~dx = \int^{1}_{0}\frac{d}{dz}f(x,z) ~ dx. $$

So,

$$\frac{d}{dz}\int^{1}_{0} f(x,z) ~dx = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{\int^{1}_{0}f(x,z +h)~dx -\int^{1}_{0}f(x,z) ~dx}{h} = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\int^{1}_{0}\frac{f(x,z+h)-f(x,z)}{h}~dx.  $$

We wish to "push" the limit inside the integral, so we will use the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem. Observe that, $\forall h \in [0,1], \forall x \in [0,1], \exists c \in [z,z+h]$ such that:
$$\frac{f(x,z+h) - f(x,z)}{h} = f'(x,c) \implies |\frac{f(x,z+h) - f(x,z)}{h}| \le f'(x,c).$$
Let, $M = \max_{x \in [0,1],z \in [0,1]} |f'(x,z)|.$ Then,

$$ \int^{1}_{0} M < \infty.$$
We also have that,
$$\forall x,z,h \in [0,1]: ~ ~ |\frac{f(x,z+h) - f(x,z)}{h}| \le M.  $$

We can then use the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem, in order to obtain:

$$\frac{d}{dz}\int^{1}_{0} f(x,z) ~dx = \int^{1}_{0} \lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x,z+h)-f(x,z)}{h}~dx = \int^{1}_{0}\frac{d}{dz}f(x,z) ~ dx.$$

Any issues with this proof? Thanks.

Comment: Seems fine to me :)